# How to name classes with similar semantic in Java?

Tags: java

For example, in C#, `Foo`, `Foo<T>`, `Foo<T1, T2>` could have similar semantic but are different classes. But in Java, I can't name classes like that. How to name them? I don't think `Foo`, `Foo1<T>`, `Foo2<T1, T2>` are appropriate. Any other suggestions?

Actually, I want to design some interfaces which have only one method just like `Runnable`. But `run` in `Runnable` doesn't have return value and any parameters. I want interfaces like

```
public interface Runnable<T>{
    void run(T t);
}

public interface Runnable<T, TResult>{
    TResult run(T t);
}

public interface Runnable<T1, T2, TResult>{
    TResult run(T1 t1, T2 t2);
}
```

And so on. And I think they are better in the same package.

Comment: What's your use case? In C#, there's a `Tuple<>` where you have variadic type parameters, but what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? You should keep your namespace clear. If you really must, you can prevent the name clashing by putting each `Foo` into different packages.

Comment: The usual reason in C# is that `Foo` is a non-generic supertype of `Foo<T>`. You use it when you don't know the type of T, in cases where the language can't infer the type. It also helps when legacy code written for non-generic types like `IEnumerable` can accept an `IEnumerable<T>` instead.

Comment: @CraigStuntz Yes, that's another scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rename them to truly reflect their function:

```
BasicFoo
GenericFoo<T>
SuperDuperAdvancedFoo<T, U>
```

you can even declare an interface, say Foo, that provides all the methods every well-behaved Foo should have. Then you implement the interface in different Foos with different type parameters:

```
interface Foo<T, U>
BasicFoo implements Foo<Object, Object>
GenericFoo<T> implements Foo<T, Object>
SuperDuperAdvancedFoo<T, U> implements Foo<T, U>
```

EDIT: working at your examples, the 3 interfaces can really be declare just using one of them:

```
public interface Runnable<T1, T2, TResult>{
    TResult run(T1 t1, T2 t2);
}
```

and if you don't want any parameters, you just supply Void whenever necessary. A Void class in uninstantiable, so the only other possibility is to pass or return null. So for example:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable<Void, Void, Void>;
```

creates a method similar to

```
void run();
```

You actually declared

```
Void run(Void a, Void b);
```

but Void in uninstantiable, so you must pass nulls and the function will always return null.

Comment: I have edited my question. But it seems only different names can solve the problem.

Comment: Good, but then you give piff poor examples of names...

Answer (score 1):

this is an issue in some functional programming libs where they have classes for different arity functions.

[guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/index.html) avoids the issue by only support a single argument - if you want multiple args you use a wrapper.  and since guava seems to be right on so much, i suspect that's the best answer: don't do this.

but [functional java](http://functionaljava.org/) uses F1, F2, ... so you would not be alone if you went that route.  [bolts](https://bitbucket.org/stepancheg/bolts/wiki/Function) is similar, but [fun4j](http://www.fun4j.org/) avoids the issue by using varags without generics.

i know my reply may seem fanboy-ish, but the guava people spend a lot of time [worrying](https://plus.google.com/113026104107031516488/posts/ZRdtjTL1MpM) about how to fit things into java in a good way; i bet they considered and discarded the numbered approach.